# WSO2 API Manager: Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons

Tags: cors, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using the WSO2 API manager via docker. And I want to transform soap API to rest. When I send a request in the devportal I get this error:

"Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS

Network Failure

URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS requests."

I enabled CORS, but the error has not gone. I should mention that I've sent the request from another system, not local.
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I hope you are using Devportal Try-out UI to invoke this API. Can you get the same error if you use another client like Postman? And Have you added "Request Headers" for the particular resource on API? If yes, have you put that header to the core request headers as mentioned here[1]? [1]. https://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/adding-request-headers-to-published-apis/

Comment: Add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes, I used Devportal. It seems to be ok in Postman. I also enabled the CORS configuration, but the error didn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I understood that the browser blocked my request based on mixed content. There are two ways:
You should change HTTP to HTTPS or follow this page: [Enabling mixed content in your browser](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/target/using/experiences/vec/troubleshoot-composer/mixed-content.html?lang=en) and enable allow for "Insecure content" permission for this IP.